# Is there any way to wait to capture the screen till application/web page open in Java?

Tags: java

I am doing the automation for the application. I want to open the application/web page and try to take capture the screen. But I am facing the issue while doing the same. I am using the Robot class of java to capture the screen. My problem is

1. Before the application opens, the screen capture function is called which doesn't include the application window I want
2. Same issue for the web page. Before web page fully loaded, screen shot is taken.

I don't want any hard delay (i.e sleep(2000)). I want to add smart delay for both of the cases. Can somebody help me with this issue? Here is the sample code.
I have already tried it with hard delay but it is working in some cases and not in some. It is hard to predict the exact delay for web page to load.

```
import java.awt.Rectangle; 
import java.awt.Toolkit; 
import java.awt.Robot; 
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage; 
import java.io.IOException; 
import java.io.File; 
import javax.imageio.ImageIO; 


public class Screenshot 
{
      public static void main(String[] args) 
      {
          try 
          {
              Runtime.getRuntime().exec("calc");
              Robot robot = new Robot();
              Thread.sleep(200);
              String path = "D:// calc.jpg";
              Rectangle capture = new
              Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
              BufferedImage Image = robot.createScreenCapture(capture);
              ImageIO.write(Image, "jpg", new File(path));
              System.out.println("Screen Captured); 
          }
          catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) 
          {
              System.out.println(ex);
          }
      }
}
```

It should wait till calc window open and then take the screen shot. Now it depends on the system load how much time the calc window take to open. Same for the web page.  I want a smart delay to wait until the  application/web page open.

Comment: It might make more sense to use Selenium instead, since most drivers support screenshots directly.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other way we can try?